# TimeZone Clarification - LINUX env

Tags: linux, datetime, time, oozie, oozie-coordinator

One of my current jobs(oozie coordinator) is set at `2018-03-26T14:08Z` UTC. This runs every day 10PM IST.

Would you please explain the FORMAT it's showing. I want to reset the job to 4PM IST.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The format is described in this W3 Note: [Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Specifically, your string `2018-03-26T14:08Z` is **Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:08:00 +0000**, according to:

> Complete date plus hours and minutes:
>   `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD`
>
> Where:
>
> - `YYYY` = four-digit year
> - `MM`   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
> - `DD`   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
> - `hh`   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
> - `mm`   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
> - `TZD`  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

To set it to **4PM IST**, use **`2018-03-26T10:30Z`**, because, according to Google:

> Indian Standard Time is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Coordinated Universal Time.